# Connect-ServiceFabricCluster doesn't work after "Reset local cluster"

Tags: powershell, azure-service-fabric

After running "**Reset local cluster**" using the task tray icon for a [local Service Fabric cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started-with-a-local-cluster) the `Connect-ServiceFabricCluster` powershell command is no longer able to connect to the cluster in a powershell window where that command previously succeeded.

## Before reset

Connect works fine:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Connect-ServiceFabricCluster
True
WARNING: Cluster connection with the same name already existed, the old connection will be deleted


ConnectionEndpoint   :
FabricClientSettings : {
                       ClientFriendlyName                   : PowerShell-46eba43f-9981-4a04-93ce-dcc8bc707059
                       PartitionLocationCacheLimit          : 100000
                       PartitionLocationCacheBucketCount    : 1024
                       ServiceChangePollInterval            : 00:02:00
                       ConnectionInitializationTimeout      : 00:00:02
                       KeepAliveInterval                    : 00:00:20
                       ConnectionIdleTimeout                : 00:00:00
                       HealthOperationTimeout               : 00:02:00
                       HealthReportSendInterval             : 00:00:00
                       HealthReportRetrySendInterval        : 00:00:30
                       NotificationGatewayConnectionTimeout : 00:00:30
                       NotificationCacheUpdateTimeout       : 00:00:30
                       AuthTokenBufferSize                  : 4096
                       }
GatewayInformation   : {
                       NodeAddress                          : localhost:19000
                       NodeId                               : bf865279ba277deb864a976fbf4c200e
                       NodeInstanceId                       : 131314568099152528
                       NodeName                             : _Node_0
                       }
```

## Reset

"Reset local cluster" manually with tray icon right-click, then:

## After reset

Connect fails if run again in same powershell window:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Connect-ServiceFabricCluster
WARNING: Failed to contact Naming Service. Attempting to contact Failover Manager Service...
WARNING: Failed to contact Failover Manager Service, Attempting to contact FMM...
False
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster : The object is closed.
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-ServiceFabricCluster
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Connect-ServiceFabricCluster], FabricObjectClosedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TestClusterConnectionErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.ConnectCluster
```

## New window

Start a new powershell window and `Connect-ServiceFabricCluster` works there, but the original powershell window never recovers.

---

I can't work out where it's hiding the state it's using to remember the broken connection.

I tried deleting the `$ClusterConnection` variable to no effect.

```
Remove-Variable ClusterConnection
```

I had a look at `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\ServiceFabric\` but it's a compiled .net module so not the easiest to follow.

---

related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38104087/10245

Comment: Actually, a colleague pointed out that the local service fabric cluster is a development tool, and nothing to do with service-fabric deployed in production, so this really is a developer question not an infrastructure question. As such I've re-opened it here and deleted the serverfault copy.

Comment: posted as feedback: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/293901-service-fabric/suggestions/18240553-fix-object-is-closed-error-after-local-cluster-r

Answer (score 9):

That's a [known](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-troubleshoot-local-cluster-setup#cluster-connection-failures) issue.

> Cluster connection fails with "Object is closed" Solution Close the
>   current PowerShell window and open a new PowerShell window as an
>   administrator. You should now be able to successfully connect

Comment: Thanks for finding an authorative reference, much appreciated.

Comment: I ran into this 4 years since this was asked, solution still works.